# Why won't Google Chrome's script debugger let me set a breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, scripting, google-chrome

I'm running Google Chrome 8.0.552.215 on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. I have a simple jQuery inline script much like any I've successfully debugged in the past:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // do stuff here
    // but reduced to a simple
    alert('here!');
  });
</script>
```

I'm browsing to the secure (https) section of the site I'm working on.

There are no script errors, the scripts all run just fine, but I can't set a breakpoint.

I tried debugging this in Firefox's Firebug and and can set and hit breakpoints just fine.

Why would this happen?

Comment: I think this has happened to me too, so I'm curious as to what the deal is.

Comment: I had this problem recently because my jQuery id selector did not exist.

Comment: I solved this problem for myself by clicking on the De-obfuscate Source button in the corner of the Chrome Source Viewer (it looks like double-angle brackets.  I.E. "{ }")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug was fixed yesterday (February 3) with the introduction of a new api for managing JavaScript breakpoints: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69988

I downloaded the most recent Chromium nightly from http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/ and was able to successfully set breakpoints in JavaScript, which I had been unable to do using the current stable/beta/dev builds of Chrome.

Hopefully this fix will be incorporated into the next releases of Chrome. Until then, adding debugger; statements to your code is a decent workaround for setting breakpoints.

Answer (score 6):

Does this happen when you refresh the page when the developer tools are already open? It happened to me too in that case.

Workaround:

1. Set resource tracking to always enabled.
2. Close the developer tools.
3. Refresh the page.
4. Open the developer tools, tab resources.
5. Set your breakpoint.
6. File a bugreport [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) because it is not normal behavior.
7. Post a link to this bugreport back on SO so we can all star it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan. This is the damnedest thing, it's magically started working. I even closed the browser, checked to make sure there were no hidden chrome.exe's lurking and still it refused to let me set a break point. Then I come along try it again and blow me it works. Grr.

Comment: Did my method help you? Try again after refreshing the page (with the tools still open), does it still work?

Comment: I followed your method but whether that solved it or not is hard to say. It also now  just works in the way I normally hit the debugger. Maybe a stray cosmic ray thing :)